# Definition of Jointly Normal

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, bivariate-distributions

**Problem**

X ~ N(0, 1)

Let W be independent of X with P(W = 1) = P(W = −1) = 1

Y = WX

It is found that Y ~ N(0,1).

Are X and Y jointly normal?

**Question**

Answer key said: "Clearly X and Y are not independent but uncorrelated. This implies that (X, Y ) are not jointly normal"

**Why does NOT independent & uncorrelated imply NOT jointly normal? What is the definition of jointly normal?**

Comment: Surely you should be reading this in your textbook/notes? In any case, $X$ and $Y$ are jointly normal if every linear combination of $X$ and $Y$ is a normal random variable. A classic theorem of the theory of jointly Gaussian RVs states that if $X$ and $Y$ are jointly normal, then they are independent iff they are uncorrelated. See [Lecture 21 here](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~r-ash/Stat/StatLec21-25.pdf) (Note: they use a different, but equivalent definition of joint Gaussianity. Excercise: Prove that the definition here and in the link are equivalent.)

Comment: I wish I could but unfortunately, my professor did not provide a textbook nor did he explicitly define jointly normal in his lecture slides & it's finals season - thank you for your reply!